# WebRTC android example, XMPP or Http Peer Connection?

Tags: android, webrtc

Is the example code of WebRTC example folder for Android `/root/trunk/talk/examples/android/` is it using Http Peer Connection or is it using Libjingle XMPP protocol for communicating with server?

I am trying to create example android Application with WebRTC, which will talk with my local Http server for login and call.

My server is simple http not XMPP and i want some sample code to test it for android platform, so i am thinking of using this android example code in WebRTC code base if it is basic http WebRTC client for android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To login and call (signaling part of your application) you could use socket.io. I leave you an example that worked for me:

> https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC

This application uses android-websockets library which its name was changed to AndroidAsync and you can find it here:

> https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for links. Can the library do multi-casting?